# java 8 stream: grouping by and storing sum in new object, and merge maps

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have a class Row such as:

```
class Row {
   public Long id1;
   public String id2;
   public Long metric1;
   public Long metric2;

   public Stats getStats() {
      return new Stats(metric1, metric2);
   }
}
```

and a class Stats:

```
class Stats{
    public Long totalMetric1;
    public Long totalMetric2;

    public void addMetric1(Long metric1) {
       this.totalMetric1 = this.totalMetric1 + metric1;
    }

    public void addMetric2(Long metric2) {
       this.totalMetric2 = this.totalMetric2 + metric2;
    }
}
```

I have a list of rows

```
List<Row> rowList;
```

and i need to convert it into a map grouped by id1 and id2, and i need the metric data to be summed up into Stats object in this form

```
Map<Long, Map<String, Stats>>
```

I am using java stream to generate this but stuck at this point:

```
Map<Long, Map<String, List<Stats>>> map = stream.collect(
            Collectors.groupingBy(r->r.id1(), 
            Collectors.groupingBy(r->r.id2,
            Collectors.mapping(r->r.getStats(), Collectors.toList()))));
```

How do i convert the list into another object having sum of all the objects in that list?

Also is there a way to merge two output maps of above required form into a third one using java stream?

Example:-

Input: A list of Rows

```
<1,"ABC", 1, 2>
<1,"ABC", 2, 2>
<1,"XYZ", 1, 2>
<2,"ABC", 1, 2>
<2,"XYZ", 1, 2>
<3,"XYZ", 1, 0>
<3,"XYZ", 2, 1>
<3,"XYZ", 2, 3>
```

Result: Map grouped by Field 1, Field 2, with sum of Field 3 and Field 4

```
1 - ABC - 3,4
    XYZ - 1,2
2 - ABC - 1,2
    XYZ - 1,2
3 - XYZ - 5,4
```

Comment: You like to have a `Map` from `Row` ids to a `Map` of something that is of type `String` to `Stats`. What is that something of type `String`?

Comment: where is your `Stats`-constructor taking two arguments?

Comment: do you really want a map where id1 is the key and the value is an additional map with id2 as the key and then the stats object as its value? Or does it also suffice to have a map with a compound key and the stats as its value? (`Map<CompoundKey, Stats>`, where `CompoundKey` could even be a concatenated `String`?)

Comment: @Harmlezz id2 is of String type, so i want to group by id1 in the first map and them group values of that map by id2 to have second map, id1 is of type `Long` and id2 is of type `String`

Comment: @Roland I am looking for the scenario that you described first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be to do it in bit easier way than nested collections. in Row class, add

```
public Pair<Long,String> getIds() {
   return new Pair<>(id1,id2);
}
```

in Stats class, add

```
public Stats merge(Stats other) {
    return new Stats(totalMetric1+other.totalMetric1, totalMetric2 + other.totalMetric2);
}
```

and then write something like

```
      Map<Pair<Long, String>, Stats> stats = rowList.stream().
              collect(Collectors.toMap(Row::getIds,Row::getStats, (s1,s2) -> s1.merge(s2)));
```

If you are not allergic to guava (and you shouldn't be, this is one of no-brainer libraries to include in every project, at least for me), you can write it in more elegant and readable

```
      Table<Long, String, Stats> table = rowList.stream().
            collect(Tables.toTable(Row::getId1, Row::getId2, Row::getStats,(s1,s2) -> s1.merge(s2),HashBasedTable::create));
```

without having to use Pair<> or nested maps.

Comment: Thanks Artur, this works for me!
I have followup question, what if i need to add another group by field in `Row`, is there a way for `Table` to support this?

Comment: No, Table is just 2-dimensional matrix, I don't think there is 3 or n-dimensional equivalent available with same quality. You would then need to start using Tuples (like Pair) on one of the dimensions. Benefit of Table over Pair is really that you can query/iterate/etc things over rows or columns easily. As long as you don't need such types of access, you can go on with composite keys (I would create explicit classes for anything over 2 elements).